# Gesture location + CGImage - Lost connection to iPad (Xcode 7)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a function below which worked perfectly fine on iOS 8.4.1.

It now crashes the app & sometimes the iPad restarts when I test this function.

```
func panToAdjustContrast(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    let location = gesture.locationInView(self.imageInEditorView)
    let y = location.y

    self.colorFilter!.setValue(1 - y, forKey: "inputContrast")
    if self.imageInEditorView.image != nil {
        self.imageInEditorView.image = UIImage(CGImage: self.context.createCGImage(colorFilter!.outputImage!, fromRect: self.extent))
        self.colorFilter!.setDefaults()
    }
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

1. Reset contentAndSettings iPad & setup as new iPad.
2. Cleaned, built & ran the project.
3. Stopped the app via XCode.
4. Disconnected the USB cable
5. Ran the app & still crashes the app

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I cannot see anything thay may be nil at runtime. It works perfectly fine on the iPad2 simulator.

Comment: 2015-09-20 10:23:03.949 iTX[257:7545] Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x19e792af0> { count = 1, contents =
 "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x19e792e50> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }

Comment: Still I cannot figure this out :) As soon as I pan the screen, I have 1.2+GB other processes filled up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90159/discussion-between-gokhan-dilek-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

This was magically fixed after upgrading to latest version of iOS9 at the time.